# one way sync gmail contacts to galaxy s6

Tags: contacts, gmail, samsung-galaxy-s-6

Is there a way to do a one way sync of my Gmail contacts to my phone? I want changes to my Gmail contacts to update on the Galaxy S6 but I do not want the changes on the phone to edit my Gmail contacts. In the account settings I turn the sync option off, but then it wont get my updates from Google when they are made. Is it possible to set this up or is it stuck as a two way sink?